# Linked script.js not being used

Tags: javascript, html, stenciljs

I'm building my first web App with stencil.js and until now I had my JavaScript code in my index.html file, but now I want to move my code to a separate file (script.js). But when I link script.js file it doesn't work.

Here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
  
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Booker App</title>
  <meta name="Description" content="Welcome to the Stencil App Starter. You can use this starter to build entire apps all with web components using Stencil!">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#16161d">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge">

  <script type="module" src="/build/app.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="/build/app.js"></script>  
  <link href="/build/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
  
  
</head>
<body>

  <booker-header></booker-header>
  <booker-display></booker-display>
  <booker-buttons name="Add Books"></booker-buttons>
  <booker-form></booker-form>

  <!-- <script>
    var btn = document.querySelector('booker-buttons');
    var form = document.querySelector('booker-form');

    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      
      form.open();
      
    })
  </script> -->
  


  
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my script.js file:

```
var btn = document.querySelector('booker-buttons');
var form = document.querySelector('booker-form');

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log('testing if file works');
  form.open();
});
```

I tried putting script tag before `</body>` and it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

### Original Answer, still relevant

By moving your script into an external file it can now execute before the rest of the page is loaded since the script tag is above where the commented script is in the original HTML page.

Try wrapping your entire script in the `DOMContentLoaded` event to force it to wait until all of the page has loaded.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var btn = document.querySelector('booker-buttons');
  var form = document.querySelector('booker-form');

  btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('testing if file works');
    form.open();
  });
});
```

### 404 error answer

The `src` attribute for script.js starts with `./` and not `/` like all of the other resources you're loading in the header. Technically that's a relative reference which is ok, as long as script.js is right next to the HTML file in the directory tree.

Check your directory tree and make sure you have something like this. And make sure you have script.js at the root location which appears to be right next to mainfest.json.

```
- index.html
- script.js
-build
|-app.esm.js
|-app.js
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not help, I just opened inspector and I get 404 error

Comment: Then we're discussing a completely different issue. Can you add information about the 404 to your question.

Comment: GET http://localhost:3333/script.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found), this is all I get

Comment: Is it weird that my build folder is empty?  both app.esm.js and app.js files are not there. Its says file not found when I CMD + click on them